# How to invoke outer "this" in inner function?

Tags: javascript, function

I defined two functions for array:

```
Array.prototype.remove = function(obj) {
    var i = this.length;
    while (i--) {
        if (this[i] === obj) {
            this.removeAt(i);
        }
    }
};
Array.prototype.removeAll = function(array2) {
    array2.forEach(function(item) {
        this.remove(item);  // remove not found!!
    });
}
```

But in the `removeAll` function, it reports `function remove is not found`. I fix it like this:

```
Array.prototype.removeAll = function(array2) {
    var outer = this;
    array2.forEach(function(item) {
        outer.remove(item);  
    });
}
```

But it's ugly. Is there a better way?

Comment: I don't think it's tremendously ugly, and it works.  The 'this' in your foreach is changed to be the item in the iteration, so I don't see too much of a way around it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Passing `this` via a different variable as you do is the idiomatic approach. There is nothing ugly about it. (It is more common to call the variable `that` or `self` though)

Answer (score 2):

By passing next one  argument to [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) which will be context of `this` in callback function, In your case `this` refers to window object.

```
Array.prototype.removeAll = function(array2) {

    array2.forEach(function(item) {
        this.remove(item);  
    },this);
}
```

Comment: Very nice, I did not know that.

Comment: be aware this is not supported in ie8 and earlier versions.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to using bind (if you need to support old browsers and don't wish to extend `Function.prototype`) is to simply wrap your callback in an immidate function and feed `this` in as an argument like this:

```
Array.prototype.removeAll = function(array2) {
    array2.forEach(function(outer){
     return function(item) {
        outer.remove(item);  
    };}(this));
}
```

or you can write a simple curry utility function and use like this

```
function curry() {
  var fn = Array.prototype.shift.call(arguments), 
      args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  return function curryed() {
    return fn.apply(this, args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
  };
};



Array.prototype.removeAll = function(array2) {
    array2.forEach(curry(function(item) {
        outer.remove(item);  
    },this));
}
```

If you don't mind extending `Function.prototype` you can use bind as already described by others you can find an excellent compatibility extension on MDN here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 1):

There is [`Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) and similar.

```
array2.forEach((function(item) {
    this.remove(item);  
}).bind(this));
```

It's not technically the same, as the previous the "inner this" is now shadowed/lost (and a *new* wrapper function is created), but it works nicely in some contexts.

For the most part, I prefer the standard `var self = this` ...

Happy coding.

Comment: As far as I know `Function.bind` is ECMAScript 5 which is only support by the latest browser (not supported in IE8, FF3.6, FF3.6, Safari 4, Safari 5, Safari 5.1 and Opera 10.50 - 11.50)

Comment: @StefanGehrig You are correct, hence the "and similar" :-) It's easy to implement such a function, and the MDC documentation provides such an example. This same functionality can be found in a number of frameworks.

Comment: Just wanted to note this important detail... ;-)